# Updating the price value in a CSV file based on new prices daily

Tags: csv, insert-update, createprocess

I have two CSV files. One is the master second is the daily update.

Master file has Sku#, Price, compare to price, description, images.

Daily update has Sku#, price, msrp, dist cost,short description, long description, images.

1)I need the price in the master file to get updated based on the price value in the daily update file.

2) if there is a new sku# in the daily update then that needs to be updated to the master file.

3) if there is no price change in the daily update file for an sku#  in the master file then it needs to be skipped.

4) when new values have finished updating a new temporary file needs to be created with only the headers and ski# changes so this can be uploaded. ( Trying to run this on a master CSV file contains 55,000 different SKU# and not all prices change daily)

5) needs to be as simple/ automated as possible.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Did you have a specific question?  Usually just listing a bunch of requirements doesn't fly very well here.  If all you have is requirements, then you should seek out a consultant to build the project.  If you are attempting to implement this yourself and are getting stuck, then we can help if you show the code you've written so far.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I offended you Brian Rogers. No I have no experience in coding and yes I am trying to implement this myself. I do not know or wouldn't no where to start if I did I wouldn't try and be so clear. So if you don't mind helping me figure out a solution which should not be too much of a problem for someone with your skills that would be just great.Those aren't requirements as such just what I'm trying to achieve..thanks in advance bud.